# Recover Terminal.app

Tags: macos, mac, data-recovery

I accidentally seem to have deleted Terminal.app. How can I get it installed? Google search results led me to install Pacifist.app and recover the app from the boot disk. But I'm unable to locate Terminal.app from the boot disk.

How do I go about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track.

Open Pacifist --> Open Apple Install Discs --> Contents of EssentialSystemSoftware --> Contents of EssentialSystemSoftwareGroup --> Contents of BaseSystem.pkg --> Applications --> Utilities --> highlight Terminal.app and click Install.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not pay attention to this option in the Main Menu. I can't vote you up, though I wish to. :-(

Answer (score 0):

You could open the OSX installer located on the boot disk using Pacifist and extract it from there.

h t t p : //forums.macosxhints.com/showthread.php?t=84215

(sorry new users cannot post more than one link)

Another thread about this same issue.

http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=10257853

Answer (score 0):

well in case you still don't know 
[how to recover deleted files mac](http://www.mac-how.net/), this program of MacHow just might help you)) me myself using it, can't complain - everything works fine)

Comment: Your link just links to the website and not a specific article about recovering deleted files.